# Transient buildup of capacitively coupled transistor amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, bjt, passive-networks, non-linear

I'm trying to understand the following section from "Communication Circuits: Analysis and Design" by Donald T. Hess: [image]
[image]
[image]
Here \$W(t)\$ is defined by $$W(t) = e^{\frac{q(v_i(t) - v_{imax})}{kT}}$$

How the equation 5.3-12 and $$e^{\frac{- q v_{imax}}{kT}} = \frac{I_{dc}}{I_{ES}}$$follows from equation 5.3-11? Initial condition for capacitor implies \$V_{dc}(0^+) = V_{dc}(0^-)\$ but it doesn't seem to have applied here. So what's the reason for that? How can we apply \$v_i(t) = 0\$ for \$t\lt 0\$ to the equation 5.3-11?

Comment: The author is trying to figure out how the dc conditions of the circuit are going to change with large signal excitation. (The base-emitter junction will rectify the signal some).  This is admirable, but with SPICE available to you on your personal computer, I think these equations loose practical usefulness.

Comment: @user69795 You're right but I'm trying to figure out how equation 5.3-12 was derived from equation 5.3-11.